# I need to populate a json file, now I have something like this:

Tags: javascript

```
{"element":{"$elemMatch":{"cost":100}}}
```

I tried like this

```
var elementArray=[];
elementArray.push({"element":{"$elemMatch":{"cost":100}}});
```

But I got ouput like this

```
{"element":{"$elemMatch":[Object]}}
```

How can I do this?

Comment: please, provide more code, not just results

Comment: Parse the json to an object, manipulate it, and change it back to json when you're done.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript has a JSON helper called `stringify` which makes your JSON into a string (duh), which makes it possible to transport into a file, or with AJAX. From what I can tell this is what you are trying to do.

`JSON.stringify(elementArray);`